# IPython cannot find packages in my conda-env

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda

I cannot import package `from Py6S import *` installed in my conda-env using IPython after activate the env by `activate py6s-env`, but I can successfully import in python.
Do I need set environment variable in my system path or who know the reason?

Comment: Had you activated your conda env before you installed Py6S?

Comment: I  create my conda-env and installed my packages by `conda create -n py6s-env -c conda-forge py6s`. Before import I first activate my env by `activate py6s-env`

Comment: I have some problem. In my coda environment "python" knows how to find keras, ipython doesn't.